# d3 sankey plugin not drawing when there are too many links?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, sankey-diagram

I was following this tutorial to make a Sankey chart
https://bost.ocks.org/mike/sankey/

It will draw nothing when there are too many nodes and links, it is not the circle problem.

It will say [image]

I have 349 nodes and 1776 links
[image]

It is because there are too many nodes and links?

Then I tried the new latest d3 Sankey plugin, 
https://github.com/d3/d3-sankey
but it requires the d3 version 4, but I still need the d3 version 3 for another charts, I have change the gloable.d3 to gloable.d3v4 in both Sankey and d3 v4 js file.

d3-sankey plugin file:

```
(function (global, factory) {
typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined' ? factory(exports, require('d3v4-array'), require('d3v4-collection'), require('d3v4-shape')) :
typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(['exports', 'd3v4-array', 'd3v4-collection', 'd3v4-shape'], factory) :
(factory((global.d3v4 = global.d3v4 || {}),global.d3v4,global.d3v4,global.d3v4));
}(this, (function (exports,d3v4Array,d3v4Collection,d3v4Shape) { 'use strict';
```

d3 version 4 file:

```
(function(t,n){"object"==typeof exports&&"undefined"!=typeof module?n(exports):"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define(["exports"],n):n(t.d3v4=t.d3v4||{})})(this,function(t){"use strict"
```

the graph is: 
[image]
then it shows me this error:
[image]

So my question is how can I solve the problem with the old Sankey version, if it cannot be solved, 
then how can I change the latest Sankey plugin file to work with the d3 version 4 with the global.d3v4 variable?

Please help me! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've two questions in one here, one is about versions of the `d3.sankey.js` and one is about not rendering.

### Not Rendering

I'm surprised it crashes your browser, but I'm not surprised that you get the console errors. It looks like the available space you've given to the Sankey is not enough for all the Nodes/Links so some of them are being given negative heights.

These are what cause the console errors, increasing the overall height of your chart (even if it's not all visible at once) should fix the console errors. As for the crashing the tab you probably need to hit pause a few times and see if it's stuck in a loop somewhere. My guess is that because the Sankey has some pretty intensive layout algorithms to run, it could just be spending a long time in there.

### Versions

The only reliable way I know of you use two different versions is to functionally scope them. Normally you do this by way of some modular pattern (e.g. using `import "d3"` and then webpacking. This would allow you to produce different bundles for you charts requiring different versions of `d3`.

Comment: Thanks fro your help. I have found the problem for the option 1(old Sankey) too many nodes will cause the problem. option 2 (latest Sankey), I did not set the svg height and width...

Comment: @KreedzZhen glad you got sorted. If you felt like I helped out enough feel free to accept as an answer. If not how can I improve it?

Comment: @lan your answer is correct, the console error is caused by the chart height and width which I did not set this to the svg.